Compatibility of spring-boot-maven-plugin and spring-boot
Does the spring-boot-maven-plugin version need to match the spring-boot version?
Or can an older version of spring-boot-maven-plugin be used with newer version of spring-boot and vice versa?
I cannot use spring-boot-starter-parent to keep the versions synchronized because we have a corporate parent pom. The spring-boot-maven-plugin version is defined in this parent pom, but we have multiple different spring-boot versions in use in different applications.
This has not caused any problems so far, but I fear it could cause problems at some point?

Eventually it will lead to issues. They should match, especially if you are mxing 2.7 and 3.0 for instance or 2.5 and 2.7.
